# texture does not show up when load .dae model

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to load a .dae model in three.js, but the texture does not load(I guess). here my code:

```
<script src="js/three.js"></script>

    <script src="js/Animation.js"></script>
    <script src="js/AnimationHandler.js"></script>
    <script src="js/KeyFrameAnimation.js"></script>

    <script src="js/ColladaLoader.js"></script>

    <script src="js/Detector.js"></script>
    <script src="js/stats.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

        //load collada
        var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
        loader.options.convertUpAxis = true;
        loader.load('model/Wood.dae', function(collada){
            collada.scene.traverse(function (child){
            if(child instanceof THREE.SkinnedMesh)
                {
                    var animation = new THREE.Animation (child, child.geometry.animation);
                    animation.play();

                    camera.lookAt( child.position );
                }
            });

        scene.add(collada.scene);
        });

        camera.position.z = 10;

        var render = function () {
            requestAnimationFrame( render );
            renderer.setClearColor(0xffe5e5, 1);

            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        };

        render();
```

I want to be able to change the material, and following many tutorials, but nothing is actually working. Some tips?

Comment: you dont need to keep calling `setClearColor()` in the render function. you only need to call it once at init time.

Comment: Try adding a material and map texture to that material

Answer (score 0):

I got it doing this way

```
function newTexture(texture){
            dae.traverse(function(child){
                if(child instanceof THREE.Mesh){
                    child;
                    child.material.map = texture;
                    child.material.needsUpdate = true;
                }
            });
```

and for load the texture you can use TextureLoader, it worked for me.